# Joist trak radiant tube length in last bay

Tags: heating, radiant-heating

I'm installing my first radiant floor system using 1/2 inch tubing and [Joist Trak plates](http://www.uponorpro.com/en/Modal-Pages/Products-and-Tools-Modal-Page.aspx?id=%7B99BADED5-3700-497C-8A40-00948CE4448E%7D). I purchased a 1000 foot roll of tubing and cut it into 5 200' pieces. While running my loops, I'm finding there is either extra or not enough tubing to complete the final bay. I'm able to complete 5 bays but end up with enough tubing left over to complete half the 6th bay.

My question is what do you do? Do you complete the 5th bay and cut the remaining creating a shorter loop and undesirable waste or do you complete half the 6th bay and finish it up on the next loop?

If you were to finish it up on the 2nd loop, would it be desirable to go to the end of the 7th bay come back up the 6th bay halfway meeting the hose from the 1st loop and go back down the 6th bay where you would then come back up the 7th bay?

I'm trying to keep loops even while minimizing tubing waist and extra loops, any help would be appreciated.